# AngularJS function returning promise with required parameter

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

Simple question. 
I have build this function:

```
// Gets the kit by id or slug
var _getKit = function (id) {

    // Try to get our kit using our shared service
    return sharedKitService.get(id).then(function (response) {

        // Assign the response to our service
        service.models.kit = response;

        // Return our response
        return response;
    })
};
```

and I want to add a check to the function to be something like this:

```
// Gets the kit by id or slug
var _getKit = function (id) {

    // If we have no id, exit the function
    if (!id)
        return;

    // Try to get our kit using our shared service
    return sharedKitService.get(id).then(function (response) {

        // Assign the response to our service
        service.models.kit = response;

        // Return our response
        return response;
    })
};
```

But I know that won't work because if there is no id then the function will no longer produce a promise.
I know I could do something like this:

```
// Gets the kit by id or slug
var _getKit = function (id) {

    // If we have no id
    if (!id) {

        // Defer our promise
        var deferred = $q.derfer();

        // Reject our promise
        deferred.reject();

        // Return our promise
        return deferred.promise;
    }

    // Try to get our kit using our shared service
    return sharedKitService.get(id).then(function (response) {

        // Assign the response to our service
        service.models.kit = response;

        // Return our response
        return response;
    })
};
```

but this seems like overkill. 
Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#reject):

Just `return $q.reject(reason)`. 
This returns Promise which is instantly rejected

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use

```
$q.reject();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your function as below for shorter purpose.

```
// Gets the kit by id or slug
var _getKit = function (id) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    // If we have no id
    if (!id) {
        // Reject our promise
        deferred.reject();
    } else {
        sharedKitService.get(id).then(function (response) {
            // Assign the response to our service
            service.models.kit = response;

            // Return our response
            deferred.resolve(response);
        });
    }
    return deferred.promise;
};
```